# Set System Property for an RCP Program

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP/Eclipse program and I want to provide it in 2 different flavors. Which flavor it is should be sort of hardcoded or provided as a conf setting that cannot be changed at runtime.

I was first thinking of having one specific class in my plugin duplicated and code the logic of the second flavor into that class and package it somehow as a second RCP program. Then I thought I can simple code the 2 different flavors in one class in the same plugin and differentiate by system property whether logic 1 or logic 2 is executed. Then I could've simply duplicated the RCP package and deliver one with an additional parameter in launcher.ini and the other without that parameter.

Problem is that I can't get a simple Java System Property set in an RCP program. I have tried launcher.exe -Dpropname=propvalue, I have tried adding it to launcher.ini, I have googled the web back and forth. There are lots of documents on the web explaining all the various configuration settings that you can provide as system property or as property to launcher.ini but none explains how to set custom properties.

Does anybody have an idea?

Many thanks,
Kai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to the run configuration, you will get the  arguments tab, there in VM Arguments block you can provide -Dpropname=propvalue. If you have more values you can enter with space or newline separating them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I go to the launching configuration of my product there is a vm argument text box and when I enter -Dpropname=propvalue there a -vmargs -Dpropname=propvalue is added to launcher.ini and that works. Thanks again, you've helped me a lot.